# Finding $\cos\theta$ given $\sin\theta$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We know that, $\sin(75^\circ)=\sin(30^\circ+45^\circ)=\sin45^\circ.\cos30^\circ+\sin30^\circ.\cos45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

And, $\cos(75^\circ)=\cos(30^\circ+45^\circ)=\cos45^\circ.\cos30^\circ+\sin30^\circ.\sin45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Now, $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$

So, $\cos(75^\circ)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(75^\circ)}=\sqrt{1-(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}})^2}=\sqrt{1-\frac{(\sqrt{3}+1)^2}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{8-(\sqrt{3}+1)^2}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{8-(4+2\sqrt{3})}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}$

Thus, $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}$

Now, how do we simplify the RHS to represent the LHS? I have checked that LHS and RHS both have a value of $0.2588190451$. But, I am unable to show that by simplification.

Comment: I don't think there's a general method for simplifying $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ with $a,b,c$ rational. Many terms like that just don't simplify at all.

Comment: @aschepler So the expressions are equal but we cant simplify one to get another?

Comment: Cosine is negative in the second and third quadrants, so $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ holds only for $\theta$ in the first and fourth quadrants (otherwise, $\cos\theta=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ instead).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang That doesn't really solve the problem. Does it?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "simplify". "Write a simpler equal expression", obviously yes, but it might take some guessing. "Follow a procedure to get to a simpler expression", maybe not.

Comment: Okay, there is a method which covers this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Two_nested_square_roots

Comment: Another approach which is guaranteed to be effective is to the examine the trivial quartic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ which satisfies the given root to check it for reductions. If any expression can be found, it will be obtained this way; additionally - using Eisenstein or other criteria- one can in some cases exclude the existence of such a representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify $$\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}}$$

Note that the LHS is positive, it is equvalent to verifying that

$$\left( \frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^2=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}$$

$$ \frac{3+1-2\sqrt3}{8}=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}$$

which is clearly true.

Comment: In this case we know that LHS=RHS. So, you are able to show that. But, what if someone was finding $\cos75$ through $\cos(75\deg)=\sqrt{1−\sin^2(75\deg)}$ method. Then, he/she will get stuck at the RHS expression. Then, what's the way to find LHS from there? Forget that we know the LHS while simplifying the RHS.

Comment: @SouparnaPal First of all, your presenting the distinction between derivation and verification to Siong Thye Goh is somewhat unfair.  The posted question did not explicitly ask for a derivation, rather than a verification.  Beyond that, as you probably know, $~\sin(75^\circ) = \cos(15^\circ) = \cos[(30/2)^\circ] = ~$ the known value of a nested radical by (1/2) angle trig formulas.  Therefore, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, suppose that you are given known values $A,B \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}},~~C,D \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Further suppose that you are trying to simplify the expression

$$\sqrt{\frac{A + B\sqrt{C}}{D}}.$$

Here, I am assuming that $C$ is *square free*.

By simplify, I mean find $x,y,z$ such that $z \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~ x,y \in \Bbb{Q} ~$ (the rational numbers), such that:

$$\left[\frac{x + y\sqrt{D}}{z}\right]^2 = \frac{A + B\sqrt{C}}{D}. $$

I use the following general procedure to **attempt** the simplification.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

---

First, if $D$ is not a perfect square, I find the smallest positive integer $K$ such that $DK$ is a perfect square.

Then, the expression that I am trying to simplify becomes

$$\sqrt{\frac{AK + BK\sqrt{C}}{DK}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{DK}} \times \sqrt{AK + BK\sqrt{C}}.$$

So, letting $R = AK, ~S = BK$, the problem has been reduced to **trying** to find $x,y \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that

$$\left[x + y\sqrt{C}\right]^2 = R + S\sqrt{C}. \tag1 $$

To clarify, in (1) above, I am assuming that $R,S,C$ are known, and that $x,y$ are to be determined, if possible.

---

$$ \left[x + y\sqrt{C}\right]^2 = \left[x^2 + Cy^2\right] + \sqrt{C}\left[2xy\right] \implies $$

- $\displaystyle 2xy = S \implies y = \frac{S}{2x}.$
- $\displaystyle R = \left[x^2 + Cy^2\right] = \left[x^2 + C\left(\frac{S}{2x}\right)^2\right] \implies $ 
  $\displaystyle x^4 - Rx^2 + C\left(\frac{S}{2}\right)^2 = 0.$

So, letting $w = x^2$, I convert the equation to the quadratic equation

$$w^2 - Rw + C\left(\frac{S}{2}\right)^2 = 0.$$

Then, I have that

$$w = \frac{1}{2} ~\left[R \pm \sqrt{R^2 - CS^2}\right]. \tag2 $$

Here:

- Since $w = x^2$, I must require that $w \geq 0$.
- If $\displaystyle (R^2 - CS^2)$ is not a perfect square, then the attempt has failed.

Assume that $R^2 - CS^2 = n^2 ~: n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Then, I also need that one of the following must be the square of a rational number:

- $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} ~\left[R + n\right]$
- $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} ~\left[R - n\right]$

If this is not the case, then (again) the attempt has failed.

---

If one of the above two expressions has form 
$~\displaystyle \frac{p^2}{q^2} ~: ~p,q \in \Bbb{Z^+}$

then, I set $~\displaystyle x = \frac{p}{q},$ and then
solve for $~\displaystyle y = \frac{S}{2x}.$

Assuming that this works, I also 
set $~\displaystyle x = \frac{-p}{q},$ and then again
solve for $~\displaystyle y = \frac{S}{2x}.$

Then, I have two distinct values for $\left(x + y\sqrt{C}\right),~$ and I choose the one that is positive.

---

In my experience, on the one hand, the above approach often fails.  On the other hand, I have never seen the above approach fail, when the desired simplification was available.

This means that if an alternative strategy succeeds in producing the desired simplification, then the above strategy should also succeed.

---

I should point out that I am on somewhat shaky ground.  It could be that a situation exists where the above approach fails even though the desired simplification is possible.

Personally, I have never noticed this.  However, my knowledge of **Field Theory** is practically non-existent.

So, this answer only represents the approach that I always use.  It does seem to be a practical approach.